# How to parallelize this embarrassingly parallel loop with Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I have an embarrassingly parallel loop:

```
# Definitions

def exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarityAll(inputFolder, outputFolder, similarityMeasure):
    phasesSpeedupDictFolder=parsePhasesSpeedupDictFolder(inputFolder)
    avgSpeedupProgramDict=computeAvgSpeedupProgram(phasesSpeedupDictFolder)
    parameters={
        PROGRAMSPHASESSPEEDUPDICTS:phasesSpeedupDictFolder,
        PROGRAMSAVGSPEEDUPDICT:avgSpeedupProgramDict
    }
similarityHandler= SimilarityHandler(similarityMeasure,parameters)



# Sequential running

for fileName in os.listdir(inputFolder):
    print fileName
    exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity(inputFolder + fileName, outputFolder + fileName, similarityHandler)
```

and I would like to make it parallel using `Joblib` Parallel:

```
# Parallel version

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

parallel= Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)
    for fileName in os.listdir(inputFolder):
        print fileName
        parallel(delayed(exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity(inputFolder + fileName, outputFolder + fileName, similarityHandler)))
```

*OR* other version:

```
arg_generator = ((inputFolder + fileName, outputFolder + fileName, similarityHandler) for fileName in os.listdir(inputFolder))
parallel(delayed(exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity)(arg_generator))
```

But upon running it complaints with :

```
parallel(delayed(exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity(inputFolder + fileName, outputFolder + fileName, similarityHandler)))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 516, in __call__
    for function, args, kwargs in iterable:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Amir, it looks like this program has lots of indentation issues.  Can you please fix those so that we can understand what the program is actually doing?

Comment: It looks like you are still actually *calling* `exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity` inside your loop, and then passing the *result* of that to delayed. Probably you need to just pass the function and the arguments to delayed?

Comment: Let me have a try with your answer. Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still calling `exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity` (serially) inside your loop, but then you are passing the result to `delayed`

From the docs https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#common-usage, it looks like you need to do something like:

```
parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)
parallel(delayed(exhaustiveExplorationsWithSimilarity)(inputFolder + fileName, outputFolder + fileName, similarityHandler) for fileName in os.listdir(inputFolder))
```

Comment: The same error: `File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/joblib/parallel.py", line 516, in __call__
    for function, args, kwargs in iterable:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: I guess we should modify the type of `fileName` to be iterable. right?

Comment: Not 100% what you mean by that, so... maybe!

Comment: so any suggestions on why I keep receiving this error ?

Comment: Yes, this is working now. Can you elaborate more on the change? and can you mention how am I gonna reuse the the same pool for more commands, say on every for iterations I would like to `print fileName` to see the progress

Comment: I don't really know much about `joblib`, I've tended to use the `multiprocessing` module directly. I have to say I don't really like the syntax of Parallel/delayed, I've not seen it before. Since you're wanting to do more stuff in the 'tasks', the way I would do that would be to either look at using `multiprocessing` directly, or perhaps `Celery`.